# C# mod dependency throws 'TypeLoadException' when instantiated?

Tags: c#, mongodb, dll

**Issue**

When I try to use a 3rd-party library in my C# project, it almost always throws 'TypeLoadException' at me.

**Details**

The dependency I'm using in this case is a mongodb driver, though this issue replicates with other libraries such as Json.net and MySQL. I've tested with my own self-created small 'dependency' class and I was able to use this without it throwing an exception at me.

I'm able to build successfully, but when the .dll is loaded as a mod for a game, it logs out this rather unhelpful stack trace and fails to execute anything.

```
TypeLoadException: A type load exception has occurred.
    at Test.Api.GameAwake () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at ModManager.GameAwake () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_LogException(Exception, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogException(Exception, Object)
UnityEngine.Logger:LogException(Exception, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:LogException(Exception)
Logger:masterLogException(Exception)
Logger:Exception(Exception)
Log:Exception(Exception)
ModManager:GameAwake()
GameManager:Awake()
```

All that resides in 'Test.Api.GameAwake' is a simple connection handler taken from the mongodb documentation. There's nothing else going on in this project.

I can see that the assemblies do seem to load correctly, so I'm really out of ideas as to what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a specific version dependency problem, or a missing assembly that you're not seeing.

I recommend checking a "dependency spy" program, such as http://ilspy.net/ and trying to load your assembly plugin to see what it's looking for.

Comment: I've checked the file through ILSpy - everything looks fine to me. All the needed references are loaded correctly with their respective references too.