# How to get Unity3D 2018 (or higher) to work with MongoDB C# driver?

Tags: mongodb, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get Unity3D work with MongoDB, but I am running into too many version compatibility issues.

My Unity is with Framework version 4.6.1. With C# driver 2.8.0 downloaded from NuGet package manager. 
MongoDB.Driver package has two netstandard1.5 and net452 folders. MongoDBDriver has net452 and netstandard1.5. Likewise, there are MongoDB.driver.Core.2.8.0,  Dnsclient and MongoDB.Driver.GridFS with multiple version of framework specific .dlls.
My Unity is set to .Net 4.x (Scripting run time version) and .Net standard 2.0 API compatiblity.

With these, the MongoDB name itself is not recognized while scripting.

I downloaded C# driver code from GitHub (2.8.0) and built it fresh. Copied net 1.5 version of .dlls, but it did not work either.

I have taken .DLLs from https://drive.google.com/file/d/16cLVJi0VZpplSS8MDnRcUeVnYuvxypBm/view. It builds fine (with run time version .Net 3.5 and API compatibiltiy standard 2.0). But it fails with "unknown host" probably due to some compatibility issue with Dnsclient - used by MongoDB.Driver.core.

Please let me know if someone knows the correct version combination or the process to build, specific code to modify in MongoDB C# driver code - to make it work with Unity3D.

I have seen answer on typeload exception in link below. I also faced it. But it did not solve my problem.
[C# mod dependency throws 'TypeLoadException' when instantiated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42151197/c-sharp-mod-dependency-throws-typeloadexception-when-instantiated)

Comment: I have figured out how to run MongoDb in .Net 4.x. You can download the dlls at my github: https://github.com/Julian23517/Unity-mongo-csharp-driver-dlls I try to keep it up to date.
read the README for usage :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So now again with explaination:
I have figured out how to run MongoDb in .Net 4.x. (Unity 18.3 and 19.1 tested) 
You have to Include these dlls in a Plugins folder:

```
DnsClient.dll  
MongoDB.Bson.dll  
MongoDB.Driver.Core.dll  
MongoDB.Driver.dll  
System.Buffers.dll
```

To connect to the Database (replace username, password, DATABASE_NAME and localhost (localhost only, if you host your database elsewhere)):

```
using MongoDB.Driver;

private const string MONGO_URI = "mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017";
private const string DATABASE_NAME = "testDatabase";
private MongoClient client;
private IMongoDatabase db;

client = new MongoClient(MONGO_URI);
db = client.GetDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
```

You can download the dlls at my github: https://github.com/Julian23517/Unity-mongo-csharp-driver-dlls I try to keep it up to date.

Comment: It is working very well with Unity 2018.3 Runtime 4.71 and target API compatibility level .Net 2.0.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: With pleasure. Upvote and accept Answer would be appreciated :)

Comment: I am trying to host this game on WebGL. This does not seem to work for that purpose. Please suggest the right stack and libraries to get this working.

Comment: I do not build for WebGL so I did not test it, but you can try the dlls from here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/releases/download/v2.8.1/CSharpDriver-2.8.1.zip . You can give feedback if it works.
Dlls are:
MongoDB.Bson.dll
MongoDB.Driver.Core.dll
MongoDB.Driver.dll
MongoDB.Driver.GridFS.dll
MongoDB.Driver.Legacy.dll

Comment: Hi, do you have a link which explains how you built for unity ? For some reason those drivers do not work for me... older ones with the 1.x api do tho.

Answer (score 0):

first : download the driver from this link : http://ge.tt/7xQdxUj2 
1.11.0 for Unity 4 or 5. Recommended!
This driver requires .NET 2.0 API Compatibility level and will not work with .NET 2.0 Subset.

then you can get more information from this repo :
https://github.com/janfiess/unity-mongodb

Comment: For webGL, I went for apython REST server with Flask and then HttpWebRequest based REST calls. This worked pretty well. Hence could not test the drivers. Shall keep you posted if I get to test it.

Comment: @IshwaraBhat do you have any code samples for your work, that would be highly appreciated

Comment: Unfortunately my code is too glued to overall code base. I suggest this for client side: https://github.com/oswaldocarvalho/unity-restful-client  . You need to build a python (or nodeJS) back end server that interacts with mongo DB. Though it is pain to learn new syntax, it is fairly simple to do.

Comment: For the back-end though, the cloud learning curve seems unavoidable. i.e. getting cloud account, permissions,  then being familiar with aws/google cloud/ other clouds. Here is a sample back end code https://github.com/serverless/examples/tree/master/aws-python-rest-api-with-pynamodb. Your solution needs to have both.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why all send their githubs. Maybe to advertise themselfs. But there are all dlls for working with MongoDB could be found in the NuGet. It is the right place to get fresh version, because Mongo developers manage them by themselfs. I absolutely not sure these guys, who send their githubs, keep all dlls versions fresh.

https://www.nuget.org/profiles/MongoDB

Comment: i installed through nuget and VS doesn't recognize those packages installed. I cannot do "using MongoDB.Driver;". That's why people are posting the DLLs outside of nuget, because it is a pain to make it work.